# Same file name different INODES

Tags: files, filenames, inode

I recently discovered on a machine with RHEL6:
`ls -lbi`

```
917921 -rw-r-----. 1 alex pivotal  5245 Dec 17 20:36 application.yml
917922 -rw-r-----. 1 alex pivotal  2972 Dec 17 20:36 application11.yml
917939 -rw-r-----. 1 alex pivotal  3047 Dec 17 20:36 application11.yml
917932 -rw-r-----. 1 alex pivotal  2197 Dec 17 20:36 applicationall.yml
```

I was wondering how something like this can be achieved ?

Comment: try `ls -lb` to show you any trailing spaces etc.

Comment: Hi Steve, the names are identically , I've checked multiple times, and these 2 particular files are baffling the autocomplete also

Comment: Maybe expand the question to include the command you're running to get that output, and also the output of `ls -lib` ?

Comment: I was able to move one of them : `find . -inum INODE -exec mv {} new_file_name  ` but I am very curios this feat was accomplished .

Comment: If you have GNU ls, you can `run ls -lQ` to see a quoted version of the filename. One of the files may have trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @dejdej: "Hi Steve, the names are identically , I've checked multiple times" - That should not be possible.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. :) It is a different name so they have different inode. Also,when you edit a file and save it with vim it produces different inode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to reproduce that behavior. See for example:

```
ls -lib
268947 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8 Dez 20 12:32 app
268944 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24 Dez 20 12:33 aрр
```

This is on my system (`Linux debian 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

I have a UTF-8 locale and the character `p` in the above output is not the same, but it looks similar. In the first line it's a `LATIN SMALL LETTER P` and in the second line a `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER` (see https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=p&r=None). This is just an example, it could be every character in the filename, even the dot.

When I use a UTF-8 locale, my shell gives the above output. But if I use a locale that has not all unicode characters for example the default locale `c`, then the output looks as follows (you can change the local by setting `LC_ALL`):

```
LC_ALL=c ls -lib
268947 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8 Dec 20 12:32 app
268944 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24 Dec 20 12:33 a\321\200\321\200
```

This is because the `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER` is not present in ASCII.

Comment: But in your answer, the names are different, whereas the OP *explicitly* commented: "Hi Steve, the names are identically , I've checked multiple times".

Comment: @JörgWMittag The user never say anything about their locale though, so it's plausible that "checking multiple times" never included setting the locale to the C locale, and therefore getting the same-looking output every time, in their UTF-8 locale.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah, but that isn't possible. The file names _will_ be different, it's just not a difference that can be seen when using simple `ls`.

Comment: It may help to know that, on all implementations of Unix _except_ for MacOS, file names are treated as opaque sequences of _bytes_, not characters, by the kernel.  You can put absolutely any sequence of bytes you want in a directory entry, as long as none of the bytes have value 0x2F (path component separator, ASCII '/') or 0x00 (C string terminator, ASCII NUL).  Interpreting the byte sequence as some encoding of characters is entirely user space's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Two files with different inodes, but apparently the same name (French).Chaos' excellent answer put me on the track: the two characters é in the name of the second file are different from those of the first file.
the files don't have the same inode:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ ls -li 2020\ 06\ 03\ CR\ R*

9586921 -rw-rw-r-- 1 francis francis 107933 jun  4 18:53 '2020 06 03 CR Réunion équipe.docx'

9569690 -rw-rw-r-- 1 francis francis 107933 jun  4 17:11 '2020 06 03 CR Réunion équipe.docx'
```

and they don't have exactly the same name:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ LC_ALL=c ls 2020\ 06\ 03\ CR\ R*

bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (c)

'2020 06 03 CR Re'$'\314\201''union e'$'\314\201''quipe.docx'  '2020 06 03 CR R'$'\303\251''union '$'\303\251''quipe.docx'
```

and their contents are identical:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ cmp '2020 06 03 CR Réunion équipe.docx' '2020 06 03 CR Réunion équipe.docx'
```

The explanation is that in the name of the second file, é is UTF8 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (C3 A9), in the first LATIN SMALL LETTER E + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (65  CC 81) :

[image: Hexa dump of the two file names]

Attention, by pasting LATIN SMALL LETTER E + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT in a web form, it can be transformed into LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE.